# Return Date from Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

[image: Example 1 Image]

I need to find the last date an SKU was updated please. There could be blanks or zeroes in the data so I need to exclude them.

Answer (score 2):

This will find the last date that is not blank or 0:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,AGGREGATE(14,6,(COLUMN($B2:$D2)-1)/(($B2:$D2<>"")*($B2:$D2<>0)),1))
```

[image]